# Lookup a JSON array based on an ID to get additional fields using Dataweave in a Loop

Tags: json, dataweave, mulesoft, anypoint-studio, mule4

How do you do find elements for a key in another json using dataweave?

I have to 2 JSON arrays; one which is standing lookup data and second which I am creating dynamically and I need to lookup the values based on a key from my lookup json.

For e.g. My lookup array looks like:

```
[{"id": 1, "shortname": "John", "fullname": "John Doe", "age" : 40,"designation": "Engineer"},
{"id": 2, "shortname": "Mary", "fullname": "Mary Jane","age" : 36,"designation": "Manager"}]
```

Now when I looping through my payload, I only get the id in it from my API Response and I need to add the shortname and fullname for the id passed to me in the final response. Something like below:

**Input Payload is:**

```
[{
  "id": 1,
  "project": "ABC",
  "rate": "150"
}
{
  "id": 2,
  "project": "ABC",
  "rate": "200"
}]
```

**Output Payload required is:**

```
[{
  "id": 1,
  "fullname": "John Doe"
  "shortName": "John"
  "project": "ABC",
  "rate": "150"
}
{
  "id": 2,
  "fullname": "Mary Jane"
  "shortName": "John"
  "project": "ABC",
  "rate": "200"
}]
```

**The dataweave expression I am trying to write is:**

```
payload map(item, index) -> {
 "id": item.id,
 "fullname": "Lookup from other array based on id",
 "shortname": "Lookup from other array based on id",
  "project": item.project,
  "rate": item.rate
}
```

How can I get the value of **fullname** and **shortname** from another array based on the id as I am modifying the  response payload? I don't want all the data from my lookup Array rather only specific fields.

Comment: in any questions like this please be sure to highlight input examples, expected outputs for those inputs, and actual outputs (if any).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use one of the join functions from the Arrays module, like [leftJoin()](https://docs.mulesoft.com/dataweave/2.4/dw-arrays-functions-leftjoin). The after joining do the mapping to the final expected output.

In general don't think about transformations in terms of 'looping'. DataWeave is a functional language. Think on terms of mapping, filtering, etc.

```js
%dw 2.0
output application/json
import * from dw::core::Arrays
var lookup=[{"id": 1, "shortname": "John", "fullname": "John Doe", "age" : 40,"designation": "Engineer"},
{"id": 2, "shortname": "Mary", "fullname": "Mary Jane","age" : 36,"designation": "Manager"}]
---
leftJoin(payload, lookup, (left) -> left.id, (right) -> right.id ) 
    map(item, index) -> {
        (item.l),
        "fullname": item.r.fullname,
        "shortname": item.r.shortname
    }
```

Output (for the input shared):

```json
[
  {
    "id": 1,
    "project": "ABC",
    "rate": "150",
    "fullname": "John Doe",
    "shortname": "John"
  },
  {
    "id": 2,
    "project": "ABC",
    "rate": "200",
    "fullname": "Mary Jane",
    "shortname": "Mary"
  }
]
```

Comment: Ok, so Let me modify my question, my lookup array has lots of additional data that I don't want to get in the newer array that I am building and hence the need for lookup. leftJoin() will bring everything into new array which is not going to work.

Comment: That's what map() is for. If you want a more detailed answer be sure to include more detailed inputs and expected examples as I mentioned in my other comment.

Comment: You only shared the 'lookup' array. What is the input? And please use codeblock format for data, errors and code. Don't use blockquote format.

Comment: or enclose your code in 3 backticks characters ("`"). See https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting for more details on formatting samples.

Comment: I cleaned up my post to make it more legible, apologies for the confusion

Comment: What the input payload looks like? Always share the input. And the lookup is not an array if not inside brackets. They are not optional.

Comment: I updated the example further to articulate the problem, hope that helps.

Comment: Yes, it does. I shared a more detailed solution.